# how to update a custom list when there is a changes in excel sheet uploaded in document library

Tags: custom-list

I have  created a document library in which m uploading a excel sheet with values in it and i have created a custom list with same no.of.rows and columns in the excel sheet given the same name of columns.  Now i have to make sure that whatever changes i do in the excel sheet should automatically gets updated in custom list in sharepoint

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do what you specify then you should register a [Event Receiver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231563.aspx) listening for ItemUpdated and then have custom code in here updating the list.

But why are you uploading the excel sheet instead of updating the list directly?